# Extract original slice from SliceStorage and SliceStorageMut

Tags: rust, slice, nalgebra

I am working on some software where I am managing a buffer of floats in a `Vec<T>` where `T` is either an `f32` or `f64`. I sometimes need to interpret this buffer, or sections of it, as a mathematical vector. To this end, I am taking advantage of `MatrixSlice` and friends in `nalgebra`.

I can create a `DVectorSliceMut`, for example, the following way

```rust
fn as_vector<'a>(slice: &'a mut [f64]) -> DVectorSliceMut<'a, f64> {
    DVectorSliceMut::from(slice)
}
```

However, sometimes I need to later extract the original slice from the `DVectorSliceMut` with the original lifetime `'a`. Is there a way to do this?

The `StorageMut` trait has a `as_mut_slice` member function, but the lifetime of the returned slice is the lifetime of the reference to the `Storage` implementor, not the original slice. I am okay with a solution which consumes the `DVectorSliceMut` if necessary.

**Update**: Methods `into_slice` and `into_slice_mut` have been respectively added to the `SliceStorage` and `SliceStorageMut` traits as of `nalgebra` v0.28.0.

Comment: Have you tried `Into::<&mut [f64]>::into`?

Comment: Yep. It's not currently implemented.

Comment: What do you mean "not implemented"? Works fine in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd885d02843dadb3abeb86ead48a1aba)

Comment: Instead of editing the question, please add the update as an answer, since it solves the original problem. You can accept your own answer (although you don't get rep for it) and it will help other people with similar issues to find the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods `into_slice` and `into_slice_mut` which return the original slice have been respectively added to the `SliceStorage` and `SliceStorageMut` traits as of `nalgebra` v0.28.0.

Answer (score 2):

Given the current API of `nalgebra` (v0.27.1) there isn't much that you can do, except:

- life with the shorter life-time of `StorageMut::as_mut_slice`
- make a feature request for such a function at `nalgebra` [(which seems you already did)](https://github.com/dimforge/nalgebra/issues/920)
- employ your own `unsafe` code to make `StorageMut::ptr_mut` into a `&'a mut`

---

You could go with the third option until `nalgebra` gets update and implement something like [this](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.27.1/src/nalgebra/base/matrix_slice.rs.html#190) in your own code:

```rust
use nalgebra::base::dimension::Dim;
use nalgebra::base::storage::Storage;
use nalgebra::base::storage::StorageMut;

fn into_slice<'a>(vec: DVectorSliceMut<'a, f64>) -> &'a mut [f64] {
    let mut inner = vec.data;
    // from nalgebra
    // https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.27.1/src/nalgebra/base/matrix_slice.rs.html#190
    let (nrows, ncols) = inner.shape();
    if nrows.value() != 0 && ncols.value() != 0 {
        let sz = inner.linear_index(nrows.value() - 1, ncols.value() - 1);
        unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(inner.ptr_mut(), sz + 1) }
    } else {
        unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(inner.ptr_mut(), 0) }
    }
}
```